# Windows mass rename folders in folders

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, rename

I want to loop through subdirectories of all directories of current dir. The part $f in $g doesn't work. What's the correct way?

```
foreach ($g in dir) { foreach ($f in $g) { // do sth}}
```

Also I want to have access to $g and $f file names in the //do sth code block.

EDIT:
I never did anything in power shell so I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge;d

Comment: In your scenario, `$g` is a file or directory, so the inner loop doesn't really make sense. You wouldn't do `foreach($var in "C:\Some\file.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` - a cmdlet that retrieves items inside a container (such as a folder on a file system).

To retrieve child items from all sub-directories recursively, you can use the `-Recurse` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Root\Folder\ -Recurse
```

`Get-ChildItem` also has switches for only returning files or directories (`-File` and `-Directory` respectively).

So your loop (if you're just interested in directories) could look like this:

```
foreach($Directory in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Root\Folder\ -Recurse -Directory){
    Rename-Item $Directory -NewName $($Directory.Name + "_2")
}
```

This would append a `_2` to each directory name.